# Ignite Cluster getting stuck when new node Join or release

Tags: ignite, in-memory-database, gridgain

I have 3 node cluster with 20+ client and it's running in spark context.Initially it working fine but randomly get issue whenever new node i.e. client try to connect with cluster.The cluster getting inoperative.I have got following logs when its stuck.If I restart any Ignite server explicitly then its release and work fine.I have use Ignite 2.4.0 version. same issue produced in Ignite 2.5.0 version too.

client side Logs
Failed to wait for partition map exchange [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=44, minorTopVer=0], node=4d885cfd-45ed-43a2-8088-f35c9469797f]. Dumping pending objects that might be the cause:

```
        GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=44, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_JOINED, evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=4d885cfd-45ed-43a2-8088-f35c9469797f, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 10.13.10.179, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:0, /127.0.0.1:0, hdn6.mstorm.com/10.13.10.179:0], discPort=0, order=44, intOrder=0, lastExchangeTime=1527651620413, loc=true, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=true], done=false]
```

Failed to wait for partition map exchange [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=44, minorTopVer=0], node=4d885cfd-45ed-43a2-8088-f35c9469797f]. Dumping pending objects that might be the cause:

```
        GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=44, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_JOINED, evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=4d885cfd-45ed-43a2-8088-f35c9469797f, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 10.13.10.179, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:0, /127.0.0.1:0, hdn6.mstorm.com/10.13.10.179:0], discPort=0, order=44, intOrder=0, lastExchangeTime=1527651620413, loc=true, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=true], done=false]
```

Failed to wait for initial partition map exchange. Possible reasons are:
^-- Transactions in deadlock.
^-- Long running transactions (ignore if this is the case).
^-- Unreleased explicit locks.

Still waiting for initial partition map exchange [fut=GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [firstDiscoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=4d885cfd-45ed-43a2-8088-f35c9469797f, addrs=

Server Side Logs
Possible starvation in striped pool. Thread name: sys-stripe-0-#1 Queue: [Message closure [msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridDhtTxPrepareResponse [nearEvicted=null, futId=869dd4ca361-fe7e167d-4d80-4f57-b004-13359a9f2c11, miniId=1, super=GridDistributedTxPrepareResponse [txState=null, part=-1, err=null, super=GridDistributedBaseMessage [ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=139084030, order=1527604094903, nodeOrder=1], committedVers=null, rolledbackVers=null, cnt=0, super=GridCacheIdMessage [cacheId=0]]]]]], Message closure [msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridDhtAtomicSingleUpdateRequest [key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=984, val=null, hasValBytes=true], val=BinaryObjectImpl [arr= true, ctx=false, start=0], prevVal=null, super=GridDhtAtomicAbstractUpdateRequest [onRes=false, nearNodeId=null, nearFutId=0, flags=]]]], o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$DeferredUpdateTimeout@2735c674, Message closure [msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridDhtTxPrepareRequest [nearNodeId=628e3078-17fd-4e49-b9ae-ad94ad97a2f1, futId=6576e4ca361-6e7cdac2-d5a3-4624-9ad3-b93f25546cc3, miniId=1, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=20, minorTopVer=0], invalidateNearEntries={}, nearWrites=null, owned=null, nearXidVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=139084030, order=1527604094933, nodeOrder=2], subjId=628e3078-17fd-4e49-b9ae-ad94ad97a2f1, taskNameHash=0, preloadKeys=null, super=GridDistributedTxPrepareRequest [threadId=86, concurrency=OPTIMISTIC, isolation=READ_COMMITTED, writeVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=139084030, order=1527604094935, nodeOrder=2], timeout=0, reads=null, writes=[IgniteTxEntry [key=BinaryObjectImpl [arr= true, ctx=false, start=0], cacheId=-1755241537, txKey=null, val=[op=UPDATE, val=BinaryObjectImpl [arr= true, ctx=false, start=0]], prevVal=[op=NOOP, val=null], oldVal=[op=NOOP, val=null], entryProcessorsCol=null, ttl=-1, conflictExpireTime=-1, conflictVer=null, explicitVer=null, dhtVer=null, filters=null, filtersPassed=false, filtersSet=false, entry=null, prepared=0, locked=false, nodeId=null, locMapped=false, expiryPlc=null, transferExpiryPlc=false, flags=0, partUpdateCntr=0, serReadVer=null, xidVer=null]], dhtVers=null, txSize=0, plc=2, txState=null, flags=onePhase|last, super=GridDistributedBaseMessage [ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=139084030, order=1527604094933, nodeOrder=2], committedVers=null, rolledbackVers=null, cnt=0, super=GridCacheIdMessage [cacheId=0]]]]]], Message closure [msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridDhtAtomicDeferredUpdateResponse [futIds=GridLongList [idx=2, arr=[65774,65775]]]]], Message closure [msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateRequest [key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=1016, val=null, hasValBytes=true], parent=GridNearAtomicAbstractSingleUpdateRequest [nodeId=null, futId=49328, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=20, minorTopVer=0], parent=GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateRequest [res=null, flags=needRes]]]]], Message closure [msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridDhtAtomicDeferredUpdateResponse [futIds=GridLongList [idx=1, arr=[98591]]]]], Message closure [msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridDhtAtomicDeferredUpdateResponse [futIds=GridLongList [idx=1, arr=[114926]]]]], Message closure [msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateRequest [key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=1016, val=null, hasValBytes=true], parent=GridNearAtomicAbstractSingleUpdateRequest [nodeId=null, futId=32946, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=20, minorTopVer=0], parent=GridNear

Comment: "Failed to wait for partition map exchange" means there is smth that blocks topology update procedure. E.g. unreleased locks or unfinished transactions or some node is failed, but cluster waits for long failureDetectionTimout before drop node from topology.

Please, check if grid can access client node with addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 10.13.10.179, 127.0.0.1] via communication ports.

Would you please share a full log to we can continue investigation?

Comment: Thanks @AndreyMashenkov
I will share full logs.

Comment: an issue occurred when we try to put multiple objects sequentially in the cache. So instead of put, we are using putAsync now